# Table Values Overlap into Next Column of My Paper?

Tags: tables, two-column, size

```
    \begin{table}[h]%The best place to locate the table environment is directly after its first reference in text
\caption{\label{tab:table1}%
A table of the original periods and calculations of $g$ with the overall corrections.
}
\begin{ruledtabular}
\begin{tabular}{ l @{\qquad} ccccc }
\textrm{Number of Trials}
\textrm{Average Period}&
\textrm{Initial Angle}&
\textrm{Approximate $g$ Value}&
\textrm{Correction 1}&
\textrm{Correction 2}\\
\colrule
2 & 2.54 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
C & 2. & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
Al & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{tabular}
\end{ruledtabular}
\end{table}
```

I am making a 2 column scientific paper and I am trying to put a table in, but my table columns overlap like I just have a 1 column paper. The table graphic of the two lines above and below my table work fine, but the columns of text themselves like "Correction 1" jut into the second column of my paper. How can I tell LateX to just make the font size smaller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow many of the techniques described in [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/5764)

Here I use some of them, but most importantly, I completely reduce the column headers using abbreviations and some assumptions of common short-hands:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,lipsum,makecell}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{A table of the original periods and calculations of~$g$ with the overall corrections.}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{.5\tabcolsep}%
  \begin{tabular}{ l @{\qquad} ccccc }
    \toprule
    Trials &
    \makecell[b]{Avg \\ Period} &
    \makecell[b]{Init. \\ Angle} &
    \makecell[b]{Approx. \\ $g$ value} &
    Corr.\ 1 &
    Corr.\ 2 \\
    \midrule
    2 & 2.54 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    C & 2. & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    Al & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2-5]

\end{document}
```

Within a `twocolumn` document you have to make some sacrifices placing your content in a column-wise `tabular`. The other options would be to place your `tabular` inside a `table*` (at the top of the page, spread across both columns).

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to fix the bug where when I paste your code in the black bars disappear? I keep having that bug.

Comment: Oh I think it is because I am using revtex4